# How to set screen boundaries python turtle

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

How do I set screen boundaries so when the turtle reaches the edge it will stop or turn around

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
s=turtle.Screen()
p=t.xcor()
p1=t.ycor()

x=300
y=300
s.setup(x,y)

t.color("white")
s.bgcolor("black")

def up():
  player=False
  while player==False:
    t.speed(1)
    t.fd(10)

def right():
  t.speed(0)
  t.right(90)

def left():
  t.speed(0)
  t.left(90)

s.onkey(up,"up")
s.onkey(right,"right")  
s.onkey(left,"left")
s.listen()
```

I thought this would stop it at the edge of the screen
The code below isn't completely done but I didn't know what to change it to

```
while p and p1 != x and y:
  t.right(90)
  if p and p1 == x and y:
    t.speed(0)
    t.right(180)
```

Comment: in other graphic systems/modules when you have to move 100pixels then you do: move few pixel (ie. 2 pixels), check collisions (ie. with screen border), move few pixel again, check collisions again, etc. - so you run it in loop.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised your code works as 'up' isn't recognized as a valid keysym on my turtle system -- it has to be capitalized: 'Up'.  Perhaps it's a Unix / Windows schism.

Rather than move one or two pixels at a time testing if you crossed the boundary, here's another approach.  Move forward a reasonable amount, detect when you've crossed the boundary, undo that movement forward, turn around, redo your movement forward:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500

DISTANCE = 10

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.bgcolor('black')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.color('white')

def up():
    turtle.forward(DISTANCE)  # try first and undo on error

    x, y = turtle.position()

    if not -WIDTH / 2 < x < WIDTH / 2 or not -HEIGHT / 2 < y < HEIGHT / 2:
        turtle.undo()  # undo error
        turtle.left(180)  # turn around
        turtle.forward(10)  # redo movement but in new direction

def right():
    turtle.right(90)

def left():
    turtle.left(90)

screen.onkey(up, 'Up')
screen.onkey(right, 'Right')
screen.onkey(left, 'Left')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

If you add any other movement functions, e.g. `Down` for moving backward, then move the boundary crossing logic into its own function and share that with all the movement commands.

Answer (score 1):

Like furas said you'll need to move a couple pixels at a time in a loop and check for collision.  I needed a similar function recently, here it is if you want to try it.  I've never used python turtle.screen but I'm sure you could define the edges in a list, because I used this code in a for loop of lines it shouldn't touch.

```
def online(point,edge):
  first = edge[0]
  second = edge[1]
  firstx = first[0]
  firsty = first[1]
  secondx = second[0]
  secondy = second[1]
  if firstx <= point[0] <= secondx and firsty >= point[1] >= secondy:
    return(True)
  elif firstx <= point[0] <= secondx and firsty <= point[1] <= secondy:
    return(True)
  elif firstx >= point[0] >= secondx and firsty >= point[1] >= secondy:
    return(True)
```